# Angular: How do I dynamically add ng-hide to a template that was loaded via templateUrl?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to build a directive that reduces boilerplate for text fields, where the server-side declarations of things like field visibility can be passed in via a model.

I want to load the HTML for a general field from a templateUrl, transform the DOM of that (adding in various attributes and directives to this template) according to the model.

I've got it binding the proper ng-model to the nested input field, but when I try to apply an ng-hide to the top-level element, it shows up in the DOM but does no take effect.

If it were working properly, the code (so far) should be hiding the field, but it is not.

The code is at http://jsbin.com/AHoLAnUg/1/edit, and is reproduced below:

```
angular.module("directives", []).

directive('tuTextField',
          function() {
            return {
              restrict: 'E',
              replace: true,
              compile: function(ele, attr) {
                    var element = jQuery(ele);
                    var input = jQuery(element.children('input')[0]);
                    // These work:
                    element.attr('id', attr.id);
                    element.attr('class', attr['class']);
                    // this fails: (I've tried element.attr() as well)
                    attr.$set('ngHide', attr.model + ".invisible['" + attr.field + "']"); 
                    // but this WORKS:
                    input.attr("ng-model", attr.model + ".fields." + attr.field);  
              }, 
              templateUrl: '/AHoLAnUg/1.css'
            };
          }).

controller('v', [ '$scope', function(scope) {
    scope.state = {
      fields: {
        name: "Tony"  
      },
      invisible: {
        name: true
      },
      readonly: {
        name: true
      },
      validations: {
        name: {
          pattern: "^[a-zA-Z]",
          message: "Must begin with a letter"
        }
      }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: You should probably add a watcher on the model and update the attr whenever that watcher is triggered

Comment: I just dont get your point. Jsbin example is different to the code pasted here. Where does the input element come from? **ng-hide** instead of **ngHide** ?

Comment: The input element is on the template, which I've tucked into the css area so I can serve it from a URL in jsbin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't manipulate the root element of directive because `compile` function is called after `$compile` service finish its job, but you CAN manipulate child elements since they'll be compiled after their parent.

This is an example for directive execution order: 
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bateast/5Nu74/)

That's why `ngHide` in your example won't take effect but `ngModel` will.
Try wrapping your template with another  and manipulate them as you want.

Comment: Ah. That's the ticket. Thank you.

Comment: After more study, what I wanted was to use the compile service as part of the post link step. This allowed me to re-process the template so that things work correctly.